# How to get VLC to shut up with it's prefetch errors?

Tags: python, libvlc

Python 2.7 lib-vlc keeps printing `[00000000081257d0] prefetch stream error: unimplemented query (264) in control` whenever a new song plays

p.play() causes the issue.

I've found in a few places that this error means literally nothing and that VLC just outputs it for seemingly no reason. I haven't found any way around it.

I found a few threads explaining how to silence another library's prints using this code, but it didn't have any effect.

```
save_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = io.BytesIO()
self.p.play()
sys.stdout = save_stdout
```

Since there was no result, is there any way to hush vlc from spamming the console with prefetch errors?

Comment: You sure this error is being printed to `stdout` not `stderr`?

Answer (score 4):

```
Console logger (console)
  -q, --quiet, --no-quiet        Be quiet
                                 (default disabled)
          Turn off all messages on the console.
```

https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/

Comment: I ran this, it didn't seem to change anything or even send anything other than opening VLC. Since I'm not running the VLC executable from my code, is there a way to get this to save?

Answer (score 3):

I had a look at the VLC source code, and the error message in question is generated [in the C code](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/26fef56c52e12142735b980e0e8f49e15debd307/modules/stream_filter/prefetch.c#L422), and is written to stderr. This means two things:

1. Redirecting stdout won't work, as stdout and stderr use different file handles.
2. Redirecting at the Python level won't work, as Python's sys.stderr only wraps the C-level stderr; it doesn't alter it.

To make it work, you need to redirect stderr at the C level. Eli Bendersky has a [great writeup](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/) about redirecting C-level stdout in Python; maybe you can adapt that code for stderr, and to work with Python 2.

Comment: Coming from the mentioned blog post, Min RK made a package which solves this pretty well https://github.com/minrk/wurlitzer