# Playing .mp3 in Python from an URL

Tags: python, audio

I am trying to play audio in my python code where I am taking a response from a free dictionary API and trying to play the pronunciation of the word. I am doing a GET request from https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/hello and from the response I am extracting the audio URL from obj[0]['phonetics'][0]['audio'].

I am playing it using vlc

```
import vlc

url = obj[0]['phonetics'][0]['audio']
p = vlc.MediaPlayer("https:{}".format(url))
p.play()
```

It does play correctly, but after I quit my app it displays an error:
[0000021593639c90] prefetch stream error: unimplemented query (264) in control

I was not able to find a way to remove this error. How do I stop it from printing this error message? Are there other alternatives to play the .mp3 from the URL? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the output and redirect it somewhere else.

Python's `contextlib` has a couple of context managers for redirecting `stdout` and `stderr`. I don't know which you need but the code would be something like:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from io import StringIO

with redirect_stdout(StringIO()):
    p.play()
```

This is using [**`redirect_stdout`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout).

edit: This approach doesn't work as the stdout is coming at the C library level. See [this article](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/), and [this third party library](https://github.com/minrk/wurlitzer) which can help.

Comment: So I added your snipped and ran the program in Ubuntu, it's still printing the prefetch stream error message on the console. Also the same output in Pycharm as well. What is the next step?

Comment: Edit the question. Did you try the `redirect_stderr` instead of `redirect_stdout`? Be as precise as you can. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I have tried with both stderr and stdout but it didn't work. It was still printing the error message. I referred to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55897360/how-to-get-vlc-to-shut-up-with-its-prefetch-errors/55912891 . It was something to do with redirecting at C level.

Comment: @AvishekPaul I've updated my answer, but I wonder whether we should close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: I believe it can be closed.